# How to create a footer on ion-card

Tags: ionic2, ionic3

How to craete footer on ion-card. Tried these example as below but not working.please help

.Html

```
<ion-card class="dashboardgraph">
    <ion-card-header class="cardheader">
      CNC 10
     </ion-card-header> 
    <ion-footer class="cardfooter">
      footer here ///    
     </ion-footer>
</ion-card>
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to use ion-col and ion-row in ion-card.It works.

```
<ion-content fullscreen>
  <ion-card>
   <ion-card-header class="cardheader">
      CNC 10
    </ion-card-header> 

    <ion-card-content>
     Content of the card
    </ion-card-content>

    <ion-row class="cardfooter">
      <ion-col>
            <p>Footer goes here </p>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Yeap, this is the recommended/best way to add a _footer_ on an `ion-card` component

Comment: Works in Ionic 4.

Answer (score 5):

Using and completing the other answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47975359/4280561

Here goes the all code:

the HTML :

```
  <ion-card class="has-card-footer">
      <ion-card-header>
          CNC 10
      </ion-card-header> 

      <ion-row class="card-footer">
          <ion-col>
              <p>Footer goes here </p>
          </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
  </ion-card>
```

and the CSS :

```
.card-footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.has-card-footer {
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}
```